# How to automatize writing from a template in several files depending on different inputs with a script?

Tags: scripting

Everybody knows how long and tedious it can be to write cover letters, especially when looking wordwide for a master degree. Therefore I wrote a template file with variables at the place I want to write specific sentences I stored in a second file depending on the master. How can I generalize a script to fill in the variables of the first file in several files dependng on the master?

Here is the cover letter template :

```
Dear Madam, dear Sir,

I want to join Master X1 because blablabla...
I want to specialise in X2 in order to X3...
```

And here are what the variables are equal to for instance :

```
X1 : MODO// ISI// MIAGE-IF
X2 : Optimization // Artificial Intelligence // Financial Computer Science
X3 : Optimize things // replace my brain ;) // make money :p
```

I tought of scripting because `sed` is a powerfull tool to do it but I ony know how to do it for a specific query. If you think of other languages or even tool, I'm open to be critcized !

Comment: Speaking as somebody who receives these letters, please don't do this.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Promise, I won't it was also and mainly to understand how to improve `sed` on a multi-input/output way !

Comment: Here the `sed` command with respect to args.txt in my answer below `sed 's/^\(.*\) , \(.*\) , \(.*\)$/Dear Madam, dear Sir,\n\nI want to join Master \1 because blablabla...\nI want to specialise in \2 in order to \3... /g' args.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to recommend writing letters in that way. With respect to your purpose of variable substitution, transpose your table (args.txt):

```
MODO , Optimization , Optimize things
ISI , Artificial Intelligence , replace my brain ;)
MIAGE-IF , Financial Computer Science , make money :p
```

and iterate over rows:

```
while IFS=',' read -r a b c; do

echo "Dear Madam, dear Sir,

I want to join Master $a because blablabla...
I want to specialise in $b in order to $c..."

done < args.txt
```